# Python class as thread, doesn't print input

Tags: python

I'm running `Python 3` and are trying to create my own class for `threads`:

```
class myThread(multiprocessing.Process):
  def __init__(self, i):
    multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
    self.i = i
  def run(self):
    while True:
      print(self.i)
```

When creating the thread, it doesn't output `i`:

```
multiprocessing.Process(target=myThread, args=[5]).start()
```

Comment: Are you trying to run a thread or a process? `multiprocessing` is for running code in seperate processes, whereas `threading` does it in the same process. You could technically use a threading.Thread subclass and run it as a process (`multiprocessing.Process(target=myThread(5).run).start()`), but I don't see the point of doing that.

Comment: I'm running it as a process so I can terminate it.

Comment: You could run it as a thread and do `while self.running`; then you could change that flag from outside to terminate the thread.

Comment: Changed type to multiprocessing.Process.

Comment: Need to call class now with `myThread(5).start()` seems to work

Answer (score 0):

You have to create instances from the class that inherits from **threading.Thread** and use the start method in order to start the block in the **def run()** block:

```py
import threading

class myThread(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, i):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.i = i
  def run(self):
    while True:
      print(self.i)



for num in range(5): # number of threads to create
    _definition = myThread(i = 'myoutput')
    _definition.start()
```

Comment: When not using a `class` but a simply `def` it works by calling `.start()` directly as in my example. Doesn't seem to change much by creating the instance and then call `start`

Comment: May the difference be because you did not pass the i argument in that multi process line ? Creating an instance worked for me in python 3.7.4

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that this only creates a thread in the process. It doesn't start that thread.

```
multiprocessing.Process(target=myThread, args=[5])
```

You could do the following but the combination of a Thread and a Process in this manner is somewhat redundant as one could have used the main Thread of the Process instead.

```
import threading
import multiprocessing

class myThread(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, i):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.i = i
  def run(self):
    while True:
      print(self.i)

def wrapper(i):
    t = myThread(i)
    t.start()
    t.join()

if __name__=="__main__":
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=wrapper, args=[5])
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

The following does the same but without the Thread:

```
import multiprocessing

def my_target(i):
    while True:
        print(self.i)

if __name__=="__main__":
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_target, args=[5])
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Comment: Yes, but I would like to have other functions to my process, so I can update `self.i` while it's running.